Postfix Email Sending Policy
I have a postfix based mail server and I am trying to segregate email accounts into two groups. Group one I have,
 john@excaliber.com tony@excaliber.com usman@excaliber.com. Group two I have jane@excaliber.com scott@excaliber.com 
I want email accounts in group one to be able to send email only to mynetwork i.e. excaliber.com while email accounts in group two can send email to anywhere using postfix restrictions. I want to know if this is achievable with postfix or any other mail library.

This is what I have done so far

I Created a file to specify restrictions for the two groups. /etc/postfix/sender_restrictions.
john@excaliber.com   reject
tony@excaliber.com   reject
usman@excaliber.com  reject
Create the hash map from the file:
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sender_restrictions




I edited  /etc/postfix/main.cf file to include the new restrictions. 
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_restrictions,
    reject_unauth_destination



 I Configured SMTP Restrictions Based on Recipient Domain
For Group 1, 
I Create Recipient Restrictions
/etc/postfix/recipient_restrictions:
john@excaliber.com   check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_restrictions
tony@excaliber.com   check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_restrictions
usman@excaliber.com  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_restrictions
---Define the Allowed Domains
Create the file /etc/postfix/recipient_restrictions:
excaliber.com  OK
This allows users from Group 1 to send emails only to the excaliber.com domain.
--- Create the Hash Map for Recipient Restrictions
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_restrictions


New I reload postfix -
sudo postfix reload


When I test my configuration, users in group one are completely rejected from sending emails. I get an error with 550 on roundcube, recipient address rejected. Please I need help. Thanks in advance

